# Edit provisioning profile from IPA

Tags: ios, objective-c, profile, provisioning, ipa

This is VERY SERIOUS and I need very fast answer because my Demo after 3 hours.

I've IPA with large space sent to my client, on that IPA I've added only one device, after that I've added 8 devices after updating the provisioning profile (which is not updated in the IPA I've sent to my client).

I am asking is there a way to edit my provisioning profile from the IPA I sent to the client?

Can my client add more devices on the provisioning profile from his old IPA?

Comment: Not code related, at all. Ask in the Apple developer forums.

Comment: Try e-mailing the new profile to the device?

Comment: no, that is not possible, you need to re-archive the project with the proper distribution profile (with including the UDIDs).

Comment: But you can install a provisioning profile without necessarily installing the app. I'd install the provisioning profile on the device that *does* contain the correct device IDs. I'm just not sure if the `embedded.mobileprovision` file inside the IPA always overrides the ones installed on the device. If so, you could try deleting the app and deleting `embedded.mobileprovision` from the IPA, and reinstalling it. (I don't think the provisioning profile is part of the code signature.)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know - no. You need to re-create IPA with proper provisioning profile

Answer (score 0):

No The IPA needs to be built against that provisioning profile with all the devices in it. It was changed when you added those devices and needs to be rebuilt.

Allowing a user / application to modify the IPA outside of Xcode would defeat the purpose of all the inbuilt security.

You must rebuild it and send it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can't edit the provisioning profile. They're created and signed by Apple.

This might violate your dev program's TOS but a quick fix could be

1. Invite the client to your developer program
2. regenerate the provisioning profile
3. send new provisioning profile to client
4. client resigns IPA with

`xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v your.app -o`pwd`/resigned.ipa" --sign client-code-signing-identity --embed new-provisioning-profile.mobileprovision`

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to update the provisioning profile inside the IPA and resign the IPA.

A person with an apple developer account can take an IPA created with a provisioning profile for 9 devices and replace the provisioning profile with one that has 20 devices (and resign the IPA).

I've actually created [a tool to do just that](https://github.com/ROM-Knowledgeware/IPASign).